# JSON errors of LoginController and RegisterController should be strings not arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.14 (`php artisan --version`). I am using Laravel to create just a REST API.

When I get errors, the shape of it looks like this:

```
[
    'message' => 'The given data was invalid.',
    'errors' => [
        'email' => ['The email field is required.'],
        'password' => ['The password field is required.']
    ]
]
```

My

We see inside the `errors` array, each field (`email`, `password`) instead of being strings, is an array of a single string. Can there ever be more then one error is this why it is an array? Even if there is more then one error, I wanted to tell Laravel just report the first error without an array, is this possible?

In my `api.php` I have this:

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

My `LoginController.php` looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = $this->guard()->user()->load('pets');
        $user->generateToken();

        return $user;
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();

    if ($user) {
        $user->api_token = null;
        $user->save();
    }

    return ['ok' => true];
}
```

And my `RegisterController.php` looks like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user->generateToken();

    return response()->json($user, 201);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: can you please show us $this->validateLogin($request) implementation??

Comment: Thanks @Sohel0415 - I can't find a `validateLogin` method inside `LoginController.php`, is there anywhere else that it can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `validateLogin` to the following or you could give it a `different` name and call it from your `controller` function-

```
public function validateLogin($request){
  $rules = [
        'user_name' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errorResponse = $this->validationErrorsToString($validator->errors());
        return response()->json(['message' => 'The given data was invalid.', 'errors' => $errorResponse],400);
    }
}
```

And make another function to `transform` your response to expected format with this method-

```
private function validationErrorsToString($errArray) {
    $valArr = array();
    foreach ($errArray->toArray() as $key => $value) {
        $valArr[$key] = $value[0];
    }
    return $valArr;
}
```

And don't forget to add this at the `start` of your controller file-

```
use Validator;
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors):

> The `$errors` variable will be an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`

An example of displaying errors [from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors):

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you sir. However I'm not using blade or php to render. I am using react. Specifically `redux-form`, so I needed `errors` to be `field name: string` if possible.

Comment: @Blagoh you can transform the object into anything you want before sending it to React. If you want strings, create one variable per error message and send these variables to React.

Comment: Is there a single/global place I can edit that will do this for all errors? I'm not that great with Laravel so these chats on SO are really helping me learn.

Comment: @Blagoh you can create a transformer method similar to [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) for that.

Comment: Thanks Alexey I'll try it out.